# VB. Net and MongoDB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, mongodb, insert, hierarchical

How can I make  Hierarchical insert (and retireve the same )in mongoDB using VB.net (without MVC or Linq)?

sample data:

{ "placeName":  "Testplace",
  "properties": { "property1":"value1", "property2":"value2"},
  "creator":    "MrX"
}

I am using the mongodb C# driver. There isnt a problem with regular inserts having non-hierarchical data.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: have you trued using the BSONDocument ? It will allow you to crate type of BSON.Array where you can put the embedded items

Answer (score 0):

I am giving the C# code hoping you can easily convert in VB.NET

```
     BsonDocument properties = new BsonDocument().Add("P1", V1).Add("P2",V2);
     BsonDocument doc = new BsonDocument();
     doc["placeName"] = "TestPlace";
     doc["properties"] = properties;
```